# Angular js, protractor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor and angular js, I am working on testing a small todo list box,
here is the element to inspect

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label>add</label>
```

I want to know two things,how can we use a enter key , once we enter a todo list. I tried using

```
input.sendKeys(value, protractor.Key.ENTER);

input.sendKeys(value);
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

nothing worked. Also what locators should I use to get multiple checkboxes checked as we enter more than one todo list.The enter is not working correctly and I am getting an error `No element found using locator: By(css selector, input[type=checkbox])` Thanks for the response.

Below is my code

```
 it('should have placeholder text in the new todo input', function() {

    var text = element(by.css('.new-todo')).getAttribute('placeholder');
    expect(text).toEqual('What needs to be done?');
    });
  

    it('should add a new todo', function() {
    var newTodo = element(by.css('.new-todo'));
        newTodo.sendKeys('buy beer');

    var firstTodo = element(by.css('.new-todo'));
    var text = firstTodo.getAttribute('value');

     expect(text).toEqual('buy beer');
     var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
     enter.perform();

  });

    it('validate the todo item list', function(){

    var checkItem = element(by.css("input[type=checkbox]")).click();
    expect(element(by.css("input[type=checkbox]")).isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
      });

});
```

Comment: The title should be a short summary of the question.

Comment: Please read the official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing - you will find a nice example there.

Comment: The enter key still does not work. Please if someone can help me.the code is in angular 1.3. Do you this there is a problem there? I tried   input.sendKeys(value, protractor.Key.ENTER);
    OR
input.sendKeys(value);
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER); OR  var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
      enter.perform();    nothing works...